# Mongoose Geo-Query within polygon

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

somehow I'm going crazy, but let me explain.
I have a collection of documents where each document has a GPS-coordinate in the field "loc" (example below). Now I would like to query for all documents which are in a specific area.
When I do the query using MongoShell I get correct results, but when I try it using Mongoose, every single attempt fails.

As you can see below I tried different attempts using 2 and 3 [] around the Polygon coordinates.

MongoDB Version: 2.6.3
Mongoose Version: 3.8.13

Maybe someone can help me find the type or some other stupid mistake I don't see ;-(
Sadly the error message "undefined is not a function" does not help very much.

Thanks!

**Mongoose-Schema**

```
(function () {
    module.exports = function (mongoose, Schema) {

        var PointSchema = new Schema({
            _id: Schema.ObjectId,
            loc: {
                type: { type: String },
                coordinates: { type: [Number]}
            }           
        }, { collection: "points" });
        PointSchema.index({ loc: "2dsphere" });

        mongoose.model("Point", PointSchema);
    };
})();
```

**Sample document from the collection**

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("53d0d30c92a82799d8ed31d2"),
   "loc": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": {
       "0": 8.5652166666667,
       "1": 49.3288
    }
  }
}
```

**Mongo-Shell script which works**
Based on: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin

```
db.points.find( { loc :
                         { $geoWithin :
                            { $geometry :
                               { type : "Polygon" ,
                                 coordinates :  [[[8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479],
            [8.594874265234353, 49.322858939564284],
            [8.553675534765603, 49.322858939564284],
            [8.553675534765603, 49.33654935186479],
            [8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479]]]
                      } } } } )
```

**1. Failed Mongoose attempt**
*Errormessage: TypeError: undefined is not a function* - 
Tryed to take the shell script and put it into "find"

```
var Point = mongoose.model("Point");
    var pointFields = { '_id': 1, 'loc': 1 };
    Point.find({
        loc:
                             {
                                 $geoWithin:
                                  {
                                      $geometry:
                                       {
                                           type: "Polygon",
                                           coordinates: [[[8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479],
                      [8.594874265234353, 49.322858939564284],
                      [8.553675534765603, 49.322858939564284],
                      [8.553675534765603, 49.33654935186479],
                      [8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479]]]
                                       }
                                  }
                             }
    }).select(pointFields).lean().exec(function (error, result) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        processResponse(error, result, response);
    });
```

**2. Failed Mongoose attempt using 3[] **
*Errormessage: MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad geo query* - 
Based on: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2092

```
var geoJsonPoly = {
        polygon: [[[8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479],
                      [8.594874265234353, 49.322858939564284],
                      [8.553675534765603, 49.322858939564284],
                      [8.553675534765603, 49.33654935186479],
                      [8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479]]]
    };

    var Point = mongoose.model("Point");
    var pointFields = { '_id': 1, 'loc': 1 };
    Point.find({}).where('loc').within(geoJsonPoly).select(pointFields).lean().exec(function (error, result) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        processResponse(error, result, response);
        });
```

**3. Failed Mongoose attempt using 2[]**
*Errormessage: TypeError: undefined is not a function*
Based on: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2092
and http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-within

```
var geoJsonPoly = {
        polygon: [[8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479],
                      [8.594874265234353, 49.322858939564284],
                      [8.553675534765603, 49.322858939564284],
                      [8.553675534765603, 49.33654935186479],
                      [8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479]]
    };

    var Point = mongoose.model("Point");
    var pointFields = { '_id': 1, 'loc': 1 };
    Point.find({}).where('loc').within(geoJsonPoly).select(pointFields).lean().exec(function (error, result) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        processResponse(error, result, response);
    });
```

**4.Failed Mongoose attempt**
*Errormessage: MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad geo query* - 
Tried to use a full GeoJSON using 2[] around coordinates

```
var geoJsonPoly = {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [[8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479],
            [8.594874265234353, 49.322858939564284],
            [8.553675534765603, 49.322858939564284],
            [8.553675534765603, 49.33654935186479],
            [8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479]]
    };

    var Point = mongoose.model("Point");
    var pointFields = { '_id': 1, 'loc': 1 };
    Point.find({}).where('loc').within(geoJsonPoly).select(pointFields).lean().exec(function (error, result) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        processResponse(error, result, response);
    });
```

**5. Failed Mongoose attempt**
*Errormessage: TypeError: undefined is not a function* - 
Tried to use a full GeoJSON using 3[] around coordinates

```
var geoJsonPoly = {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [[[8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479],
            [8.594874265234353, 49.322858939564284],
            [8.553675534765603, 49.322858939564284],
            [8.553675534765603, 49.33654935186479],
            [8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479]]]
    };

    var Point = mongoose.model("Point");
    var pointFields = { '_id': 1, 'loc': 1 };
    Point.find({}).where('loc').within(geoJsonPoly).select(pointFields).lean().exec(function (error, result) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        processResponse(error, result, response);
    });
```

**console.trace() returns**

```
Trace
at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\Mobile\src\nodejs\analyze.js:336:17)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\Mobile\src\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:172:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (C:\Dev\Mobile\src\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.reject (C:\Dev\Mobile\src\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:111:15)
    at Promise.error (C:\Dev\Mobile\src\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:89:15)
    at Promise.resolve (C:\Dev\Mobile\src\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:107:24)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\Mobile\src\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:172:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (C:\Dev\Mobile\src\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:84:38)
```

Answer (score 3):

The GeoJSON structure in your document seems incorrect. Try specifying the coordinates as an array:

```
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("53d0d30c92a82799d8ed31d2"),
   "loc": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [8.5652166666667, 49.3288]
  }
}
```

This in combination with your fifth example should work. Also checkout the GeoJSON references on [Point](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id2) and [Polygon](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id4) regarding their structure.

---

Working example code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var PointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    loc: {
        type: { type: String },
        coordinates: { type: [Number] }
    }
}, { collection: "points" });

PointSchema.index({ loc: "2dsphere" });
mongoose.model("Point", PointSchema);

var geoJsonPoly = {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [
            [
                [8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479],
                [8.594874265234353, 49.322858939564284],
                [8.553675534765603, 49.322858939564284],
                [8.553675534765603, 49.33654935186479],
                [8.594874265234353, 49.33654935186479]
            ]
        ]
    };

var Point = mongoose.model("Point");
var pointFields = { '_id': 1, 'loc': 1 };
Point.find({}).where('loc').within(geoJsonPoly).select(pointFields).lean().exec(function (error, result) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but I copied it from Rockmongo and in it's read-only view a normal array is displayed as such. The 0: and 1: indicate the positions in the array. In the database itself it's saved correctly. The fifth example was also the one which looked most promising to me, I also rewrote it from scratch to avoid typing or copy paste error, but still no success...I just corrected it in the question

Comment: The only error I get is something like "TypeError: undefined is not a function", that's what's printed out in the execute function console.log("Error: " + error);

Comment: That still a bit vague. Does it work without error when doing a simple find query by `_id`? I'll also update my answer with a simple example script.

Comment: I tried to copy your working example coding and still get the error. "Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function" and the result is "undefined". Which versions of the DB and Mongoose are you using, maybe I can give it a try to go to another version.

Comment: I added the console.trace in the initial question any idea?

Comment: Mongo v2.6.3 and mongoose v3.8.13